# How the 1st PDO is created in case of toaster bus driver (virtual )in wdm?

Tags: windows, wdm

I am very new in wdm , so as a beginner i started with toaster sample (virtual device). During studying this , I found there is a toaster device which is connected to its bus (toaster bus) and this bus(toaster bus) is attached to root bus ... now as a bus driver for its attached device(toaster bus) , root driver has responsibility to detect the device and create PDO and then PnP manager will extract information by this pdo like h/w id etc.  But here since it is a virtual so we did it by add new h/w wizard prompt , so after the device installation I can find the h/w id and other attribute in registry but i m not able to see it after device installation ... Instead i found it after INF file loading (driver installation by manually).